# I need to select (not last child) only if it has a specific class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<td><img src="img/product.jpg" height="40" width="40"/></td>
<td>Triple monochromator for Raman</td>
<td><a href="i"></a></td>
<td>
 <a class="action--edit"><i class="icon-building"></i></a>
 <a class="action--delete"><i class="icon-building"></i></a>
 <a class="action--view"><i class="icon-building"></i></a>
</td>
```

What I need:

Add padding-left to an anchor with a class that start with action and is not last child

Selecting the anchor (not last) works:

```
a:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 5px; }
```

Try to get also the class doesn't work

```
 a[class^=action--]:not(:last-child) {
        padding-right: 5px; }
```

or

```
 a:not(:last-child) [class^=action--] {
        padding-right: 5px; }
```

Comment: `a[class^=action--]:not(:last-child)` should work. Either your problem statement doesn't correspond to what you actually want, or your HTML doesn't. Also keep in mind that a elements are inline by default, and padding works differently on inline elements. Make sure your a elements are display: block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying `padding-right` to everything except the last one, you can apply `padding-left` to everything except the first one. This will make your code much more intuitive and simple to read.

Check this out:

```
 a[class^=action--] + a {
     padding-left: 5px;
 }
```

```css
 a[class^=action--] + a {
     padding-left: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" height="40" width="40" /></td>
        <td>Triple monochromator for Raman</td>
        <td>
            <a href="i"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/24x24"/></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="action--edit"><i class="icon-building"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/16x16"/></i></a>
            <a class="action--delete"><i class="icon-building"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/16x16"/></i></a>
            <a class="action--view"><i class="icon-building"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/16x16"/></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Have a read on the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)
, the `+` mean "the immediately following `a` after every `a[class^=action--]`: so it applies on all icons, except the first one.

Comment: but he said **is not last child** .. not except the first one

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you can apply `padding-right` to everything except the last one, *OR* apply `padding-left` to everything except the first one. the result will look the same, and the second option is much more intuitive and simple to read.

Comment: ah ! so you should say it :) as i didn't pay attenting to the CSS but only the selector ;)

Answer (score 0):

The range of specified selectors should appear as follows:

```
a[class^="action--"]:not(:last-child) { ... }
```

1. Use the *attribute selector* in combination with the *caret* symbol
   to designate the beginning of a string,
2. Then chain the `:not()` `negation` *pseudo-class* selector with the
   `:last-child` *pseudo-class* selector specified between the
   parenthesis,
3. Verify that the element intended to target is in fact the *last*
   nested element amongst the range of specified elements (embedded
   code snippet below adjusted to demonstrate this)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
a[class^="action--"]:not(:last-child) {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="img/product.jpg" height="40" width="40" /></td>
    <td>Triple monochromator for Raman</td>
    <td>
      <a href="i"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="action--edit"><i class="icon-building">icon "edit"</i></a>
      <a class="action--delete"><i class="icon-building">icon "delete"</i></a>
      <a class="action--view"><i class="icon-building">icon "view"</i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i think better add some real icon or text and use a visual property so we can see the result immedialty ;)

Comment: The asker stated that this doesn't work, so I'm thinking something is wrong with the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @BoltClock. It's possible the OP could be experiencing this issue as a result of the element in question *not actually* being the last occurring instance, in which case, point #3 would still apply. I'll preserve the answer here for now pending OP's confirmation on this.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot have two pseudo selectors both the `:not` and `:last-child` are pseudo selectors only so you can't use both of them.
Instead you can use like this
`a[class^=action--]{
        padding-left: 5px; 
    }`
    `a[class^=action--]:last-child{`
    `padding-left:initial;`
`}`

Comment: check the other answers ;)

Comment: You *can* have two pseudos, and you certainly *can* have another pseudo in :not(). Whoever told you otherwise was just making it up.